# How to add ACK and PWR LED support to qemu for Raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, operating-systems, qemu, virtualization

Raspberry pi ( 2+ board) have two leds ACK and PWR , I am trying to add support for this leds in qemu raspi machine , but I am not able to understand How is these pins are controlled in the hardware level, so if any one have any idea about it please share .